# Create imgur image name

Tags: java, image, friendly-url

Take a look at the standard URL from imgur website:

```
http://i.imgur.com/zx24u.jpg
```

I was wondering how do they come up with `zx24u` string?

#### Why I'm asking:

I use MD5 to create hex digest of image and than I store it in a database. The digest looks like this:

```
8da0ed0e5862b120a886a29d7800b59b
```

I'm just wondering what should I do to get `ASCII` and url friendly image name. (I'm java user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a random number generator, seeded with the hash and fit the range of its output to your ASCII range.

```
Random r = new Random(digest);

String str = "";

while (str.length < 5) {
    int i = r.nextInt(128);

    if (i > (int)'a' && i < (int)'z')
        str += (char)i;
}
```

Comment: The entire ASCII range is not a good choice since URLs might become invalid. Perhaps you meant all alphanumeric characters or Base64 (excluding `+`).

Comment: With "your ASCII range" I meant the characters he needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the first few character for it, or you can generate a random string for identify image. I think imgur uses the second way.